# pandas groupby and agg with multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several very very large datasets like this (simplified). Notice however that not all SBs (in this case 1-4) are represented at every LFrame...

```
LFrame, Pwr, SB, Channels_Active, Channels_Assigned
     1,  10,  1,               2,                 2
     1,   2,  2,               2,                 1
     1,   4,  3,               3,                 2
     1,   6,  3,               2,                 2
    10,   8,  1,               2,                 2
    10,   2,  2,               3,                 2
    10,   4,  3,               2,                 1
    10,   2,  3,               2,                 1
    10,   5,  4,               2,                 2
```

I need to combine it in a couple ways. I believe there's a version of groupby I can use... but I can't figure it out. Maybe something like:

```
call_data_map = {
    'LFrame'             :('LFrame','first'),
    'Total_Pwr'          :("Pwr", 'sum'),
    'Channels_Act'       :("Channels_Active", 'sum'),
    'Channels_Assigned'  :("Channels_Assigned", 'sum'),
    # ??? some kind of generator? (sb :('SB', 'sum') for sb in range(1,5)) ???
}

df.groupby('LFrame').agg(**call_data_map)
```

I want the output to look like this (where I sum over the SBs to get total power in each SB and the total power overall). The cols (1-4) come from the SB col and I know the range will always be 1-4:

```
LFrame, Total_Pwr, Channels_Act, Channels_Assigned,  1, 2,  3, 4
     1,        22,            9,                 7, 10, 2, 10, 0
    10,        21,           11,                 8,  8, 2,  6, 5
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? Using list comprehension and building up the rows (on each file) is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbered columns are a pivot table, but the other columns are just a basic groupby-sum. So we could simply create them separately then concat.

```
sums = (
    df.groupby('LFrame')
    [['Pwr', 'Channels_Active', 'Channels_Assigned']]
    .sum()
    .rename(columns={'Pwr': 'Total_Pwr', 'Channels_Active': 'Channels_Act'})
    )
sb = df.pivot_table(
    index='LFrame', columns='SB', values='Pwr',
    aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
pd.concat([sums, sb], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
        Total_Pwr  Channels_Act  Channels_Assigned   1  2   3  4
LFrame                                                          
1              22             9                  7  10  2  10  0
10             21            11                  8   8  2   6  5
```

Comment: This is good... I think I can use a version of this but I have to handle when not all SBs  (7-30) are in every record. But again, I think I can figure that out.

Comment: @earnric Doesn't the `fill_value` account for that? Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: I think this a part I didn't explain: I've got several (dozen) files that I'm concatenating at the end and it could be the case that not ALL SBs are represented in any ONE file... so I don't have columns for them all (there are 30). However I was able to tweak and make your approach work! Thanks... it's the most readable.

Answer (score 3):

I would do a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index="LFrame", columns="SB", values="Pwr",
                      aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0, margins=True,
                      margins_name="Total_Pwr")
         .drop("Total_Pwr").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

​
Output:

```
print(out)

   LFrame   1  2   3  4  Total_Pwr
0       1  10  2  10  0         22
1      10   8  2   6  5         21
```

Comment: This would work, except I have 4-5 other cols that I just want copied over... like `Num_Channels, Active_Channels`. Can you incorp those into the answer?

Comment: ACtaully, those other cols I mention in the comment above need to be summed. :/

Comment: I think this can be handled. Can you update your *input/expected ouput* accordignly ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `groupby()` and `.join()`:

```
(df.groupby('LFrame').agg(Total_Pwr = ('Pwr','sum'))
.join(df.groupby('LFrame')['SB'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0))
    .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   LFrame  Total_Pwr    1    2    3    4
0       1         22  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0
1      10         21  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: You can pass `fill_value=0` to `.unstack()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the column sequence shown in OP's question, you can modify the answer by @Timeless slightly by eliminating the call to drop() and instead using pipe and iloc:

```python
out = ( df
    .pivot_table(index='LFrame', columns='SB', values='Pwr', 
        aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Total_Pwr')
    .pipe(lambda d: d.iloc[0:-1, [-1] + list(range(d.shape[1]-1))])
    .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
    .reset_index() )
```

Output:

```
   LFrame  Total_Pwr   1  2   3  4
0       1         22  10  2  10  0
1      10         21   8  2   6  5
```